# Difference between “couvrir” and “recouvrir”

Tags: vocabulaire, verbes, préfixes

They are both derived from *ouvrir*. What I mean to say is that the conjugation is the same except there is a “*c-*” or “*rec-*” before the word.

Both of them return *cover* (verb – *to cover*) on [Google Translate](http://translate.google.com). Here is *[couvrir](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/couvrir?showCookiePolicy=true)* and *[recouvrir](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/recouvrir?showCookiePolicy=true)* on [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-french).

I can't understand the difference between these two verbs. Can somebody please explain? Does *recouvrir* maybe mean *recover* or *cover again*?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean when you say *couvrir* (and *recouvrir*, of course, because *recouvrir* derives *couvrir*) are based on *ouvrir*. If you mean they come from (etymology) *ouvrir* that's really far fetched. See [ouvrir](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/ouvrir) and [couvrir](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/couvrir). Google translate is not a reliable tool and an online dictionary would easily answer your question as to the meaning of those two verbs.

Comment: *recouvrir* comes from *couvrir*. *Couvrir* comes from latin *cooperire* which was ultimately composed from co and operire (operire meaning ouvrir).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Recouvrir* is quite never used as *Couvrir une nouvelle fois* (cover again), and that's precisely because *recouvrir* and *couvrir* are two different verbs.

Laure is right in that *recouvrir* is more used when you wrap up something totally, while *couvrir* can be used in all cases, and can have many more meanings. For instance, you'd say that *le ciel est couvert* (the sky is overcast), or *sortez couverts* (which can ether mean to be careful of the weather, or "Be safe and smart")

Basically, *recouvrir* is little used and you can simply say *couvrir complètement* (totally cover) instead.

Answer (score 4):

In a general sense *Couvrir* is "to cover". But the verb has several meanings and you'd need to give more of a context.
In English "cover" will usually be followed by a preposition that will specify the meaning, and you might end up with different verbs in French. Have a look at [Reverso](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/anglais-francais/cover).

Indeed *recouvrir* is *to cover again*. But when used in a concrete sense, *couvrir* and *recouvrir* can be used to mean the same thing. Altough, to my mind, the action of *recouvrir* is more complete than the action of *couvir*.
- *Elle a recouvert le bébé d'une couverture parce qu'il faisait froid*.
Everybody will understand that she put a blanket over the baby so that it didn't get cold (and not that she tried to smother it). To my mind, using *recouvrir* here gives the feeling of the blanket going right up to the shoulders and being tucked under the baby.

Answer (score 1):

Je pensais à faire allusion à ce fils de la part de Wordreference.com: http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=290322&p=1752548#post1752548 et http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=317488.

> http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/recouvrir is an explanation in French of recouvrir. Recouvrir has two meanings,
>   ♦ one is to say that "you cover again, you add a layer on something", like if you cover a book with a plastic film to avoid that you damage the book cover.
>   ♦ On an other hand, recouvrir has a meaning of "complete cover", like for instance the snow which can cover all the surface when it's falling.
>
> After that, I think a French speaking will use both without paying attention. It is my case.
>
> I think a slight difference can be observed in the sentence:
>   - la terre est couverte de neige
>   - la terre est recouverte par la neige
>
> Here again while speaking, both can be correct lol. Depends on the people.