# « Snow covered the ground » : couvrir ou recouvrir ?

Tags: vocabulaire, traduction, usage

> Snow covered the ground and it was freezing.

Faut-il traduire « cover » par « couvrir » ou par « recouvrir » ici ?

> La neige couvrait le sol et il gelait.

ou

> La neige recouvrait le sol et il gelait.

J'ai vu qu'il y a une [question associée](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/5730/difference-between-couvrir-and-recouvrir) cependant je n'ai pas trouvé de réponse à ma question.

Comment: It seems that the subtle difference you're trying to get at **is** thouroughly explained in the answers to the question you mention; it's simply a question of insisting on the covering being complete (recouvrir) or of not insisting on that aspect (couvrir).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Les deux seraient compris mais je pense que **recouvrait** est plus couramment utilisé pour ce contexte. Cependant la phrase

> Le sol est couvert de neige

Me parait plus correcte que

> Le sol est recouvert de neige

Comment: Merci encore ! Mais pourquoi recouvrir et pas couvrir ? Et pourquoi est couvert de et pas est recouvert de ?

Comment: Les deux s'utilisent parfaitement, je t'ai juste dis ce qu'il me semble le plus naturel pour moi. Je ne suis pas sur qu'il y ait de règle précise a ce sujet et peut être même que d'autres natifs te donneraient une réponse différente :)

Comment: Indeed . À mon avis c’est très très basé sur le parlé et pas vraiment sur une règle. La neige recouvre, la couverture couvre. Même si les deux font la même chose